# How to remap Super (left) key to Control key

Tags: keyboard-layout

Could anyone please tell me how to remap my <kbd>Super</kbd> (left) key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key?

I mean <kbd>Super</kbd> (left) should work as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

Comment: Do you want only the left Super key to act as Ctrl? It's easy to remap both at once from the Keyboard Layout settings, but changing only one would have to be done through config files.

Comment: Yes, I want only left Super key to act as Ctrl..

Comment: Does the *super key* refer to the key on my keyboard that has an MS Windows logo on it an lies between Left ctrl and left alt / right alt gr and a key with another weird logo?

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger The Super key is the `Windows` key on PC keyboards  and `Command` key on Apple keyboards.  I'm no entirly sure what the other key you describe is

Answer (score 38):

To make major changes to your keyboard, including remapping characters and changing modifiers, you need to use the xmodmap utility - see `man xmodmap`. There are a couple ways to execute the changes:

- either from the command line

  ```
  xmodmap -e "your commands"
  ```
- or write the commands to a file like `.xmodmaprc`, then execute it in your login items or your .bashrc with

  ```
  xmodmap .xmodmaprc
  ```

  If you name the file `~/.xmodmap` it will be executed automatically on login.

### Now the commands

What you want to do is a two-step process. First you unmap Super from its modifier, then you map it to control.

1. Run `xmodmap -pm` in a terminal window to get a list of the bound modifiers. On my machine (and presumably yours) Super is referred to as `mod4`. `Super_L` and `Super_R` are separate keys which output the same modifier.

   Now you can unmap the modifier from it. Run the xmodmap command (using one of the methods above)

   ```
   remove mod4 = Super_L
   ```

   Now the physical key is still referred to internally as Super_L, but it doesn't do anything.
2. Now just remap it. Run the xmodmap command:

   ```
   add control = Super_L
   ```

If you want to undo this later on, just run the same commands with the appropriate arguments.

### No Super_R?

The output of xmodmap -pm might given you several keys named Super_L but none named Super_R). If it did, you now have several extra keys assigned to Control, but none assigned to Super. You'll have to rename one key. (NB: it might give you several Super_L and at least one Super_R. This is fine.)

The key names in the table all have a hex number in parentheses next to them. This number is the physical keycode of the key on your keyboard (it can vary by model). If you need to change one Super_L to Super_R, first find the keycode you want to be associated to Super_R (aren't sure which is the correct one? Run `xev` then tap the right Super a couple times. Somewhere in the maze of output is "keycode = 133" (with a different number)). Run the xmodmap command

```
keycode 133 = Super_R
```

to rename the key, then

```
add mod4 = Super_R
```

to assign it to Super.

Comment: First of all thanks for spending time for me.                                                              When I typed "remove mod4 = Super_L" in terminal I got this message: **remove mod4 = Super_L: command not found**.                                            Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/fbvEA.png

Comment: That's a command for the xmodmap utility. You have to run it by one of the methods I gave in the first section. I've edited my answer to make that more clear.

Comment: Could you also please tell me how to run those commands at startup?

Comment: When you log in, or when the system boots? If the former, just put the commands in the file '.xmodmap' in your home directory; the latter would be more appropriate for a separate question along the lines of 'how do I execute a script on startup' (such questions have presumably been asked before).

Comment: For me didn't work without _keysum_.  `keysym Super_L = Control_L`

Comment: Excellent! Great explanation!

Answer (score 23):

Command line:

```
xmodmap -e "remove mod4 = Super_L"
xmodmap -e "add control = Super_L"
```

Or put in `~/.Xmodmap` to activate on startup:

```
remove mod4 = Super_L
add control = Super_L
```

Answer (score 16):

If you want to do with with a GUI:

1. Install/open Gnome Tweaks
2. Click `Keyboard & Mouse`
3. Click `Additional Layout Options`
4. Expand `Ctrl position`
5. Select `Swap Left Win with Left Ctrl`

Comment: This will also make Left Ctrl behave as Win key. `Alt/Win key behavior` `Ctrl is mapped to Win keys (and the usual Ctrl keys)` will leave you without both left and right Win key. I haven't found the way to do it through GUI without interfering with other win/ctrl keys.

Comment: +infinite, this is exactly what I needed, thanks! now i can seamlessly move from my OSX setup to my Ubuntu Desktop!

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu, you can edit `/etc/default/keyboard` and set:

XKBOPTIONS="altwin:ctrl_win"

Which:

> Ctrl is mapped to Win keys (and the usual Ctrl keys)

Read `man 5 keyboard` for more information. You can find all possible combinations of options on your system by doing:

```
grep alt /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst | grep win
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with this:

```
clear Control
clear mod4
remove Control = Control_L Control_R
remove mod4 = Super_L Super_R
add Control = Super_L
```

Put the above lines in your `~/.Xmodmap` and execute `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`.

Answer (score 2):

There is an app called Input Remapper that has a GUI where you can easily rebind almost any key

https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper

Comment: mate! so much easier than xmodmap or keyd

Answer (score 1):

Simple and clear example of swapping Ctrl and Alt

Create a file at ~/.Xmodmap. The file content should be this:

```
! -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
! 2013-02-04

! swap Ctrl and Alt keys

! here's the default setting on special keys
!  xmodmap -pke | grep -P '(Control|Super|Alt|Menu)'

! keycode  37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
! keycode  64 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
! keycode 105 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
! keycode 108 = Alt_R Meta_R Alt_R Meta_R
! keycode 133 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
! keycode 134 = Super_R NoSymbol Super_R
! keycode 135 = Menu NoSymbol Menu
! keycode 147 = XF86MenuKB NoSymbol XF86MenuKB
! keycode 204 = NoSymbol Alt_L NoSymbol Alt_L
! keycode 206 = NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L

clear control
clear mod1
keycode 37 = Alt_L Meta_L
keycode 105 = Alt_R Meta_R
keycode 64 = Control_L
keycode 108 = Control_R
add control = Control_L Control_R
add mod1 = Alt_L Meta_L
```

Now, run this line in terminal:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

Taken from [Xah Lee: Linux, Swap Control Alt Keys](http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_swap_control_and_alt_xmodmap.html)