# Can I swap Control and Super keys using xmodmap?

Tags: xmodmap

I am trying to swap the function of CTRL left and Super Left so that I can summon lenses usng ctrl, and copy/paste using Super.

I created a .xmodmap file with the following content:

```
remove mod4 = Super_L
remove control = Control_L
add control = Super_L
add mod4 = Control_L
```

Now Super works as control, but control doesn't work as Super.

Any advice?

PS: I've found other questions about this but none that addresses my issue s far.

Many thanks!

Comment: I have read that one, but it doesn't tell me how to map ctrl to work like super

Comment: Yes, it tells you. I just tried [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/236380/147044) and works great for me.

Comment: Actually after logging out and in it doesn't work anymore, even if I manually start it from terminal... any idea?

Comment: Yes, of course. Creating only a `.xmodmap` file is not enough. See for example [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/388424/147044).